# Python Bot auto correction

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Is it possible to add a option to auto correct words in bot reply. example: In below code when we use `?ping` it reply's `hello i'm in USA now going to UK tomorrow` but it should auto correct words provided from `Autocorrect_List` it should reply `hello i'm in United States Of America now going to United KingDom tomorrow`

```
Autocorrect_List = [USA = United States Of America, UK = United KingDom]

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def ping(ctx):
    msg = "hello i'm in USA now going to UK tomorrow".format(ctx.message)
    await bot.say(msg)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need a loop and a lot of replacing. The auto correct "list" should be a dict, since dict is Python's mapping type.

```
autocorrect = {'USA': 'United States Of America', 'UK': 'United Kingdom'} 

msg = "hello i'm in USA now going to UK tomorrow"
for k, v in autocorrect.items():
    msg = msg.replace(k, v)

print(msg)
# hello i'm in United States Of America now going to United Kingdom tomorrow
```

The way you're doing it is extremely inefficient, you should consider saving the base format of the message (with the replaced messages) instead of generating everything when it's repeatedly used.

Consider using Skilledfire's solution or if you're on python 3.6+, you can use the f-string formatting:

```
d = {'USA': 'United States Of America', 'UK': 'United Kingdom'} 

msg = f"hello i'm in {d['USA']} now going to {d['UK']} tomorrow"

print(msg)
# hello i'm in United States Of America now going to United Kingdom tomorrow
```

Which can make your string somewhat readable while increasing it's efficiency level. But the best way would still be saving the message after it had been replaced.

---

A function:

```
def f(msg):
    for k, v in autocorrect.items():
        msg = msg.replace(k, v)
    return msg
```

Which you can use it as:

```
correct_string = f(old_string)
```

Comment: I’ll need to see your code to know exactly what do you mean by “it should correct automatically”, because where are you getting the string?

Comment: as i mentioned in question if we use any command  in discord channel.  if there is any word in bots message which is in `autocorrect list` it should convert. USA = United States Of America.

Comment: Yes, I think I do understand. But you see in your example, you defined the string locally, so there’s no way of accessing or modifying the string “automatically”. The best you can do for your example is add `msg = f(msg)` for all your messages.

Answer (score 0):

Yea you could do that, how about:

```
autocorrect = {'USA': 'United States Of America', 'UK': 'United KingDom'}
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def ping(ctx): 
   msg = "{}, {}    etc...".format(autocorrect['USA'], autocorrect['UK'],ctx.message)
   await bot.say(msg)
```

This seems like the quickest way to do it, but it if you wanted something more... automatic it would require a lot more effort

Edit: by a lot more effort I mean you'd need to create a different message function and it would have to check the dictionary each to it was called

Comment: Is it a one-time use thing?

Comment: this one i need to add autocorrect in all reply it will really messy i need 100s of autocorrect words. `edit` no i need it multiple reply daily usage with 100+ auto correct.

Comment: I mean one-time as in there aren't any other messages that will need autocorrect such as this

Comment: I updated my main post check it now its clearly mentioned my question. @skilledfire